# Removing even elements from a list

Tags: java, list

How can we remove even elements from a list of integers?

```
List dropEven(List l, int n) { 
    List to_return = nil();
    while(true) {
        if(l.isEmpty()) return to_return;
        if(n==0) l.remove(n);
        Integer i = (Integer)(hd(l));
        to_return=append1(to_return,hd(l));
        n= n-1;  
        l=tl(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the question in the first line, is there any issue with your code? Does it throw any exception. Or it gave unexpected output? You need to tell us.

Comment: That is what I have been using but it doesn't seem to work. So I was wondering if I am missing something. @RohitJain

Comment: Doesn't seem to work is never a good explanation of the concrete issue. You need to tell us how it didn't work. What output did you get on running this code?

Comment: Is this even java? It looks like someone is trying to twist java into a functional design pattern.

Comment: (Also, please don't mix spaces and tabs; it creates nightmares if you ever try to read the code in something that uses different tab sizes)

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the methods you didn't provide are doing?

Comment: Don't. You're already returning a new list, so just copy the odd elements to a new list and return that.

Answer (score 2):

User an iterator and remove the even values

```
Iterator i = l.iterator;
int counter = 0;
while(i.hasNext()){
i.next();
if (counter%2 == 0)
i.remove();
counter++;
}
```

Comment: this code results in java.lang.IllegalStateException, guess why

Comment: If you are using an ArrayList, it should not give IllegalStateException

Comment: [Iterator specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) doesn't change between List implementations and it says it will result in IllegalStateException

Comment: Got it.. the i.next(); was missing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner version of how to copy only odd integers into a new list and return it:

```
List dropEven(List list) {
    List toReturn = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(((int)list.get(i)) % 2 != 0) {
            toReturn.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't even compile. 2) This will throw a `NullPointerException` when `l` is not empty. 3) Returning `null` from a method that returns a `Collection` is a terrible idea. 4) `n` is never used.

Comment: @DannyMo I fixed the code. The reason it was dirty was because I tried to stay as close to the OP's code as possible, so I copied and modified.

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterator and it's remove method to remove items. You can use boolean to track even/odd numbers, not sure why would you use counter for that.

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
    boolean even = false;
    for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); even = !even) {
        iterator.next();
        if(even) iterator.remove();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```